# Upgrade Cucumber to run on latest chrome browser version

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have cucumber scripts running currently on chrome browser version 25. A update on chrome version had happened recently and I see that all cucumber jobs are failing. Please advice with necessary changes to be made can overcome this problem

Comment: the problem isn't with cucumber - it'll be on whatever webdriver you're using. Update it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried updating selenium webdriver but still the same result. I am using ubuntu and selenium --version commands says that the version is 0.2.11

Comment: If that's the case, the version of selenium-webdriver you're using is *very* old and definitely should be updated. http://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver